# Ruby yard documenting DSL method definition AND its uses>

Tags: ruby, dsl, docstring, yard

Ruby with Yard 0.9.8.
I'm defining custom attribute accessors in a `ClassMethods` module that will be extended into classed and other modules.

What I *want* to do is document what the DSL accessor methods do and attach that to their definitions, but have *invocations* of the method inherit generic docstrings about the parameters, return value, and such for each use.

However, defining the DSL docstring with `@!macro [attach]` on the definition of the accessor method isn't workable, because:

1. The macro parameters (`$1`, *&c.*) don't match correctly between the accessor definitions and the accessor invocation, and
2. I don't want the "How this attribute declarator works and is invoked" docstring to show up for both the definition *and* the uses.

So far the best I've been able to do to get the desired result is to define *two* macros:

- `@!macro [new] doc.procject.classmethod.foo.def`, which describes the declaration in the normal way you would for any method, and
- `@!macro [new] doc.project.classmethods.foo.use`, which includes the generic DSL documentation such as you'd see for `attr_accessor :foo` with no user-supplied docstring at all.

And then putting `@!macro doc.project.classmethod.foo` in the method's definition docstring, and for each actual invocation have some attribute-specific text followed by `@!macro doc.project.classmethod.foo`.  Or possibly `@!macro [attach] ...`

All this seems suboptimal and it feels like I'm missing something crucial.  The tag documentation has a few examples, but they do **not** show how the result appears.

For example, here's some simple code that shows how I'd like to see the output look:

```rb
module Outer
  module ClassMethods

    # Describing the **class method** -- the declaration.

    # @!method dsli(*args)
    # This class method declares one or more DSL interface variables.
    # @param [Symbol] args
    # @return [void]
    def dsli(*args) ; end
  end

  extend(ClassMethods)

  # Describing the **invocation** of the class *method* to create
  # an *attribute*.

>># @!attribute [rw] hoipolloi
  # This variable controls the frobbing of the potrzbi.
>># Only instances of class DSL::Thingie can be stored in this
>># attribute; any other class will result in a TypeError exception
>># being raised.
>># @overload hoipolloi
>>#   @return [DSL::Thingie,nil] the current value of the attribute.
>># @overload hoipolloi=(newval)
>>#   Sets a new value for the attribute.
>>#   @param [DSL::Thingie] newval
>>#   @raise [TypeError] if `newval` is of any class other than
>>#     DSL::Thingie.
>>#   @return [DSL::Thingie] the new value.
  dsli(:frotrzbi)

end
```

This sort of describes what I'd like to have happen.  All the lines prefixed with `>>` should be inherited (somehow) from the `dsli` method declaration.  I want to embed some of the *invocation* information in the class method's docco.  The *method*'s documentation should talk about *how*, but the docco for any *attributes* it declares should talk about *what*.  The class method's documentation applies only to its declaration, but the inherited documentation applies to **all** the attributes defined with it.

I have not been able to get this to work with YARD macros (a requirement in order to insert the proper names of the attributes, *&c.*)

*Is* there a better way to define distinct docstrings for DSL methods, one for each method's definition and another for invocations of the method *à la* `[attach]`?

Thanks!

Comment: _"but they do **not** show how the result appears"_ – just run the example trough yardoc and see if it fits your needs. From your explanation, the _"Attaching a macro to a class method (for DSL usage)"_ example in the [Tags Overview](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#macro) docs sound promising. It generates both, docs for the DSL method and separate docs for each invocation.

Comment: I tried that, and whatever was labeled as `[attach]` showed up for both the declaration of the method *and* the invocations of it.  Let me try in a more simple environment.  It might be getting complicated by my using `class << self` rather than `def self.*` to put the methods into the eigenclass; I suspect Yard is less comfortable with `class << self` declarations.

Comment: Can you show some actual code and describe the docs you’d like yard to generate? (or something similar)

Comment: I've updated the question to include YARD tags that would more-or-less result in what I want — for a one-off.  But I need to be able to do it with macros.